# How to play a video file on an iPad on a scheduled time and date on a loop for a given time in full screen?

Tags: ipad, video

I would like the iPad to play an .mp4 file on scheduled days on scheduled times in full screen? It is for a gallery set up so that no one needs to play it and play around with settings (its not possible for me to start it every day).

Comment: You need to do some research on kiosk software for iPads, secure kiosk enclosures and the like. Here’s the 1st hit I got googling for software: https://www.kioskgroup.com/pages/kiosk-pro-software   Any number of secure iPad table/desktop and freestanding stands are available.